# CORS and the new ASPNET5

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, cors

I've trying to make a request to my aspnet Web Api, with angular, with the $http module inside a factory, like:

```
http.get('http://localhost:5000/api/todo').success(function(r){ return r; }).error(function(err){ return err; });
```

**But I'm getting the following error:**

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:5000/api/todo. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin http://localhost:9000/ is therefore not allowed access.
```

I know that the request arrive to the server because I log a message when I request the resource.

[image: request arrives]

I found that I had to implement CORS at the server. I added the CORS middleware and configure my Startup file, but nothing changed.

[image: the code for CORS]

I suppose that the middleware should add the configured headers to the response, but It doesn't.
[image: response headers]

**¿What is the problem in this context?**

Comment: Move the UseCors above UseMvc,  the order of middleware matters.

Comment: You can also use the cors filter in MVC if you want more fine grain control over which routes are cors enabled.

Comment: Also make sure that asp.net is handling the OPTION request and not iis.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a small research. I found that *.WithOrigins("...")* method is not adding the *Access-Control-Allow-Origin* header, I don't know if it's the context or what, I just made an [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/CORS/issues/20) about it. I replace it with *.AllowAnyOrigin()* by now.

And also added an attribute to my controller class.

`[EnableCorsAttribute("AllowAll")]`

Of course you need to add the namespace where *EnableCorsAttribute* class is.

`using Microsoft.AspNet.Cors.Core;`

This worked for me I hope it help you, thanks for the comments.